# calling Rest Api from Django admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin

My model has 2 values.One is URL and other one is price.When creating a new object via django admin panel.I want when i input URL in input field,a request should be sent to that specific URL and fetched the updated price for the field and populate it.I have gone through documentation and helping material but did not find help.Any help in this matter is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: this sounds like something that the official documentation can help with?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
 import requests
 import json


class Model(model.Model):
    url=models.URLField()
    price=models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = request.gets(self.url)
        #assuming that json response looks like this: {'price': 2000} 
        resp_str = resp.content.decode()
        resp_dict = json.loads(resp_str)
        self.price = resp_dict.get('price')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

note: The code is not tested, but it is enough to give a general idea to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I was struglign with this for so long and finally I accomplished it.
What I did is

```
models.py
class Testone(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30,decimal_places=5)

admin.py
@admin.register(Testone)

class PriceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['url']
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.price = poang.ikea_ru(request.POST['url'])['price'] # calls external function w/ the requests data. 
#function returns dict that's why i use ['price'] to get a value from the dict
        super(PriceAdmin,self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I hope that is still helpful, I struggled with this for a little while.